# Node vs PHP SQLite performance (270ms vs 70ms) - am I doing something wrong?

Tags: php, node.js, sqlite

## UPDATE: I'm back to the original question. See the Addendum at the end

I'm trying to test Node sqlite3 read performance vs PHP, to see if moving some code to Node is a viable option. Here's what I have:

```
SQLite 3.8.7 installed on system
Node 0.10.29 with sqlite3 module (npm install sqlite3)
PHP 5.6.7 with PDO
Running on Debian 8.1
```

Test database

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE people(
  id integer primary key,
  name text,
  surname text
);
INSERT INTO "people" VALUES(1,'Elon','Musk');
INSERT INTO "people" VALUES(2,'Bill','Gates');
INSERT INTO "people" VALUES(3,'Steve','Jobs');
COMMIT;
```

Node code:

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('test.db');

db.serialize(function() {

  db.each("SELECT * FROM people", function(err, row) {
      console.log(row.id + ": " + row.name + " " + row.surname);
  });
});

db.close();
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

$dbh  = new PDO('sqlite:test.db');
$query =  "SELECT * FROM people";
foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row){
    echo "{$row['id']}: {$row['name']} {$row['surname']} \n";
}

?>
```

Node result:

```
$ time node test.js
1: Elon Musk
2: Bill Gates
3: Steve Jobs

real    0m0.281s
user    0m0.244s
sys     0m0.036s
```

PHP result:

```
$ time php test.php
1: Elon Musk 
2: Bill Gates 
3: Steve Jobs 

real    0m0.072s
user    0m0.060s
sys     0m0.012s
```

As you can see PHP version runs **4x faster**.

SQLite database is with default settings. No changes or tweaking has been done. I just wanted to get a general idea of read performance. The tests were run on old hardware.

I don't want to start any flame war. **I just want to get a general idea of how performances of Node and PHP compares** in this use case. I don't have much experience with Node so maybe I'm doing something wrong and in reality comparing apples and oranges code-wise.

Tanks for taking time to read this.

## Updated code to measure only the query execution time

Node:

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('test.db');

var preQuery = new Date().getTime();

db.serialize(function() {

  db.each("SELECT * FROM people", function(err, row) {
      console.log(row.id + ": " + row.name + " " + row.surname);
  });

});

var postQuery = new Date().getTime();
var duration = (postQuery - preQuery) / 1000;
console.log(duration);

db.close();
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$dbh  = new PDO('sqlite:test.db');
$query =  "SELECT * FROM people";

//place this before any script you want to calculate time
$preQuery = microtime(true); 

foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row){
    echo "{$row['id']}: {$row['name']} {$row['surname']} \n";
}

$postQuery = microtime(true);
$duration = ($postQuery - $preQuery);
echo $duration . "\n";
?>
```

## Result

```
PHP cli: 1.4ms
mod_php (Apache 2.4.10, opcache on): 0.7ms
Node: 3ms (but sometimes goes to 2ms)
```

As far as I can tell with this simple testing. Does the Node code above make sense?

## Conclusion

I'll try to make small REST API example on top of SQLite using both Node and PHP and compare them in a more real-life looking scenario, behind Nginx and running on server hardware.

Kenney and Jason, thanks for pointing out to an obvious blunder of not testing the query execution itself.

Nevertheless, as far as I can tell (and I might be very wrong given my lack of experience with Node), **PHP seems to be significantly faster in this specific use case**.

## Addendum

As Madara Uchiha pointed my version of Node was outdated. So I downloaded latest Node (4.1.0 linux-x64), and latest PHP while I'm at it (7.1.0-dev). I run the code above to measure the query execution time and I was surprised, to say the least.

Here's the result:

```
Node 0.10.29          3ms (sometimes 2ms)
Node 4.1.0            6ms (sometimes 7ms)
PHP 5.6.7 CLI         1.4ms
PHP 7.1.0-dev CLI     0.7ms (average)
```

**Newer Node version runs 2x slower. Why?! While PHP got 2x faster.**

What is the reason for such a dramatic slowdown with new version of Node? Does it make any difference that new version of Node I tried was not installed, ie in /usr/bin/node? I just extracted the archive to home dir and added node to PATH? Could that somehow affect the speed of execution? Both home dir and /usr/bin/node are on the same drive, same partition, same user.

## So, I'm back to original question

**Am I doing something wrong with Node and Sqlite3 here?** Or it's normal that PHP in this use case outperforms Node by order of magnitude?

Comment: You should really measure the query time rather than the application execution. NodeJS is much heavier than PHP, but once it is running it might even be faster.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll try it. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Your node version is severly outdated. Node's current version is 4.1.0.

Comment: @Madara Uchiha: I know, I'm installing latest versions of Node 4.1.0 and PHP 7.0.0 RC 3 right now :) I like JavaScript a lot and Node has great vibrant community and has made so much progress in last two years.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha FWIW, I'm not trying to prove anything here. Consider this question/thread just a "thinking out loud" I'll make some simple application and test both where and how they will actually run. There are some use cases where Node won't be able to replace PHP for me. Not because of performance but because some deployments rely on widespread cheap hosting suitable for non technical users. I would love to do everything else in Node/JS.

Answer (score 1):

You are measuring the load and JIT compile.  Profile starting just before query, after load.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party. If you don't need a verbose stack trace, don't use it:

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
```

Instead of

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
```

In a little test of your code it got 6x faster, so probably faster than PHP. You should try to utilize what NodeJS is best in, though: Asynchronous I/O.